# Breaking Alphabets into pieces, where the border intersects

Tags: inkscape, path

I have the following test typed out in my inkscape:

[image]

Now what i would really like to acheive is that every border intersection be broken into a separate piece , and then the color inside the border be another peice, let me explain what i mean.

So i have the below peice of the alphabet `L`:

[image]

So there are 4 places where the border intersects and touches , so i would like each of these borders to be broken into a separate piece and then red fill inside the border would be another piece.

As of now what i am doing is:

I Type out the alphabet , Then i go to `Path` > `Stroke to path` , and then i click on `Edit path by nodes` , then i select the text and then `Break paths at selected nodes` and then `Path` > `Break Apart`, but this is only breaking apart the alphabets and not really giving me the effect that i am looking for.

Can somebody please guide me with this please.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I'm understanding correctly, but I think you've got the right idea but you just need to duplicate your object so that you have one with fill colour and no stroke, and one with stroke and no colour. This second object is the one you'd break apart.

Do the instructions below give you what you want?

1. Convert text to path (**Path menu / Object to path**)
2. Duplicate this object and remove stroke.
   Drag the duplicate to the side.
   Remove the fill from your original object.
3. Select the node tool and click once on the
   object with the stroke & no fill to select it.
   Drag the mouse over the object.
   This will highlight all the nodes.
   On the main toolbar, click '**Break apart at selected nodes**'.
   Click **Path menu**, then **Break Apart**.
   Ungroup the paths with **Ctrl + Shift + G**

[image: Inkscape - how to break text object apart into individual paths]

Comment: did u mean `path->object o path` or did u mean `path->stroke to 
 path` in the first step ??

Comment: I meant 'object to path'. (I'm assuming you're starting out with text, so you need to convert it to a path so that it'll have nodes.) 
In my example I have red coloured text with a black stroke outline. You don't need to convert the black outline to a path. You leave it as a stroke so that you can break the nodes apart.

Comment: U mean if i have letter say `A` with no fill , just a stroke , i just need to us the node tool and select it and click on `path->break apart` , it work break apart ad each node ? ... this  does't seem to work :(

Comment: Firstly, have you converted it from text to a path? (If you click it with the Node tool, you should see the individual nodes.) Next, have you highlighted all the nodes? Using the node tool, click the object once to select it, then drag over the object to highlight all nodes. You'll see them change colour. You should now be able to break apart at each individual node. Also, you mentioned earlier that you'd tried stroke to path. I presume you haven't done this, because it won't work if you have. You can't break apart a filled object this way. It only works on a line.